# upload file (excel or csv files) and insert data into database mysql

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I need a code for uploading an excel or csv file from a form and then inserting the data from the uploaded file into the mysql database table using react js and node js (express js)

upload excel or csv file with react js and store thos file's data into database sql with express js